# CSS Rotating Images

Tags: html, css

In short: I am trying to mimic this slider but with animations, not transitions, so I can have autoplay option: [codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/HrFBx](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/HrFBx)

Explanation: 
I am working on a CSS slider that uses animations. Here is the link on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZXQEa

*Edit: I need this without script*

In code:

CSS:

```
    body { margin: 0; background: #121; }

figure { 
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1800px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  max-width: 1000px; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
}
figure img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 100%;
}
      @keyframes rotateFirst {
        0%, 20%{
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
        80%, 100%{
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
      }
      @keyframes rotateSecond {
        0%, 20%{
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        }
        80%, 100%{
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
      }
      .first{
        animation:rotateFirst 5s infinite;
      }
      .second{
        animation:rotateSecond 5s infinite;
      }
```

HTML:

```
  <figure id=blinds-window>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>

test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
test <img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
```

I have two simple challenges here as I am new to CSS animations:

1- The images don't rotate properly, it's easy to notice on my CodePen link. They probably move together.
2- I want to add text on images. I tried adding 'test' on images but it's not working on my side.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: not sure what is that you really want. The image changes on hover. Please provide more details for the first point. And for the second point, you can not add text in html, if you want the text to be a part of the animation. It needs to be a part of the image itself, because the animation is altering the image and not a dom element.

Comment: Please check updated codepen code. Thanks!

Comment: again, the rotation looks fine to me. what is your intent? how do you want them to rotate? I can see them like a card that is rotating to show the image behind. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: I want one image to rotate, with the other in background. Also one image appears suddenly, which is not what I want

Comment: You can rotate the second and see the first behind, like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRLrrG ... but how is the first going to position itself in a layer above the second and then rotate ? I think it would be great if you made some drawings and explained what the expected output should be

Comment: thanks for help! I am trying to mimic this but with animations, not transitions: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/HrFBx . Because I want it to autoplay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do, add a class (here `anim`) to the figure and change the 
hover rule from

```
figure:hover img.first { transform: rotateY(180deg);  } 
figure:hover img.second { transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(1px);  }
```

to

```
figure.anim img.first {
  animation-name: rotateus;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} 
figure.anim img.second { 
  animation-name: rotateus2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

*I also added a `@keyframes` rule and change from `transition-delay` to `animation-delay`*

***Updated:*** *Based on a comment I also added some text*

Stack snippet

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #121; } 
figure { 
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1800px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  max-width: 1000px; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
}

body::before,
body::after { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  background-size: 100%;
}
body::after { 
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg) no-repeat left top;
  background-size: 100%;
  animation-name: swapbkg;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div { 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) { 
  animation-name: swaptext2;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) { 
  animation-name: swaptext1;
}


figure img { 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

figure.anim img.first {
  animation-name: rotateus2;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
} 
figure.anim img.second { 
  animation-name: rotateus;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateus {
  0%, 80%, 100%  {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  30%, 50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
} 
@keyframes rotateus2 {
  0%, 80%, 100%  {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateZ(1px);
  }
  30%, 50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(1px); 
  }  
}
@keyframes swapbkg {
  0%, 39% {
    z-index: -1;
  }
  40%, 80% {
    z-index: -2;
  }
} 
@keyframes swaptext1 {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%, 45% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
} 
@keyframes swaptext2 {
  0%, 70%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75%, 95% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
} 

figure img:nth-child(1), figure img:nth-child(11) { 
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 840px, 0px);
  transform-origin: 50px 0px;
}
figure img:nth-child(2), figure img:nth-child(12) {
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 840px, 100px);
  transform-origin: 150px 0px;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(3), figure img:nth-child(13) {
  clip: rect(0px, 300px, 840px, 200px);
  transform-origin: 250px 0px;
  animation-delay: 200ms;  
}
figure img:nth-child(4), figure img:nth-child(14) {
  clip: rect(0px, 400px, 840px, 300px);
  transform-origin: 350px 0px;
  animation-delay: 300ms; 
}
figure img:nth-child(5), figure img:nth-child(15) {
  clip: rect(0px, 500px, 840px, 400px);
  transform-origin: 450px 0px;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(6), figure img:nth-child(16) {
  clip: rect(0px, 600px, 840px, 500px);
  transform-origin: 550px 0px;
  animation-delay: 500ms; 
}
figure img:nth-child(7), figure img:nth-child(17) {
  clip: rect(0px, 700px, 840px, 600px);
  transform-origin: 650px 0px;
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(8), figure img:nth-child(18) {
  clip: rect(0px, 800px, 840px, 700px);
  transform-origin: 750px 0px;
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(9), figure img:nth-child(19) {
  clip: rect(0px, 900px, 840px, 800px);
  transform-origin: 850px 0px;
  animation-delay: 800ms; 
}
figure img:nth-child(10), figure img:nth-child(20) {
  clip: rect(0px, 1000px, 840px, 900px);
  transform-origin: 950px 0px;
  animation-delay: 900ms;  
}
```

```html
<figure id=blinds-window class="anim">
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
</figure>

<div>Here is a text</div>
<div>Here is another text</div>
```

---

If to keep `transition` and fire it with a script, change hover rule to this

```
figure.anim img.first { transform: rotateY(180deg);  } 
figure.anim img.second { transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(1px);  }
```

*I also added an event handler, which add the class after page been loaded*

Stack snippet

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var fig = document.querySelector('figure');
  setTimeout(function () {
    fig.classList.add('anim');
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #121; } 
figure { 
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1800px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  max-width: 1000px; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
}
figure img { 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 100%;
}
figure img.first { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
figure img.second { transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateZ(1px); }

figure.anim img.first { transform: rotateY(180deg);  } 
figure.anim img.second { transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(1px);  }

figure img:nth-child(1), figure img:nth-child(11) { 
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 840px, 0px);
  transform-origin: 50px 0px;
}
figure img:nth-child(2), figure img:nth-child(12) {
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 840px, 100px);
  transform-origin: 150px 0px;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(3), figure img:nth-child(13) {
  clip: rect(0px, 300px, 840px, 200px);
  transform-origin: 250px 0px;
  transition-delay: 200ms;  
}
figure img:nth-child(4), figure img:nth-child(14) {
  clip: rect(0px, 400px, 840px, 300px);
  transform-origin: 350px 0px;
  transition-delay: 300ms; 
}
figure img:nth-child(5), figure img:nth-child(15) {
  clip: rect(0px, 500px, 840px, 400px);
  transform-origin: 450px 0px;
  transition-delay: 400ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(6), figure img:nth-child(16) {
  clip: rect(0px, 600px, 840px, 500px);
  transform-origin: 550px 0px;
  transition-delay: 500ms; 
}
figure img:nth-child(7), figure img:nth-child(17) {
  clip: rect(0px, 700px, 840px, 600px);
  transform-origin: 650px 0px;
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(8), figure img:nth-child(18) {
  clip: rect(0px, 800px, 840px, 700px);
  transform-origin: 750px 0px;
  transition-delay: 700ms;
}
figure img:nth-child(9), figure img:nth-child(19) {
  clip: rect(0px, 900px, 840px, 800px);
  transform-origin: 850px 0px;
  transition-delay: 800ms; 
}
figure img:nth-child(10), figure img:nth-child(20) {
  clip: rect(0px, 1000px, 840px, 900px);
  transform-origin: 950px 0px;
  transition-delay: 900ms;  
}
```

```html
<figure id=blinds-window>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/autumn-face.jpg alt class=first>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
<img src=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/julia.jpg alt class=second>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use JS for this task

Comment: @LoaiNajati Since the edit came a little to late (after my answer) and would make my answer invalid immediately, I move the _without script_ part. I need to run but will be back with an update without script

Comment: @LoaiNajati Updated with a non-script version

Comment: Thank you! but how do I make it play infinitely? I tried adding 'infinite' keyword on 'animation-name' property but without luck!

Comment: @LoaiNajati Updated

Comment: Thank you so much! one last question, how do I make images rotate on top of each other? I mean I don't want to see the green background when images rotate. Thanks again!

Comment: @LoaiNajati For that you'll need to put one extra image of each, layered below the other, and then make one more keyframe rule and switch their z-index between each flip

Comment: more details please?

Comment: @LoaiNajati Updated

Comment: you're a wizard

Comment: any thoughts on how to add text? I tried adding it but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @LoaiNajati Adding text how/where?

Comment: On images. Like slide text in this pen: https://codepen.io/suez/pen/vEZMoa

Comment: @LoaiNajati That code piece is not even close to the one here :) ... It is a completely new question and you should add it as such, and explain its issue and requirements.

Comment: I see. But I am trying to add text on images anyway. Not exactly with the same structure, but is there are way to add it?

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574265/simple-html-text-on-css-rotating-images